# How to Search & Replace a phrase in many HTML files at once? (Using a terminal)

Tags: linux, text-processing, files, regular-expression, html

How to delete the words "display:none;" from 100 html files at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the request you can use a variant of

```
sed -i 's/display:none;//g' *.html
```